# Game Glitch - Matching ddl.selectedvalue to a session variable

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to create a fun page that allows users to guess other members age from their profile pic. I'm new to both **asp.net** and **vb.net** language. It seems to be using the wrong age because I've done `response.write` and it says the age of person shown correctly. But it doesn't ever find a match. Here's my code.

VB

```
    While DR.Read        
        If Len(DR("profilePic").ToString) <> 0 then
           ImageProfilePicToGuess.ImageUrl = "http://teesdate.com/catalog/images/thumbnails/" & DR("ProfilePic")
           session("Age") = DR("mobilePhone")
           session("GuesseeEmail") = DR("emailAddress")
           response.write("Actual Age : " & session("Age") & session("GuesseeEmail") )
        Else

           loadProfile()
        End If

    End While
```

Here's where it checks the guess, If wrong it should move on to another profile which it seems to do.

```
    Protected Sub ddlAge_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        If session("Age") = ddlAge.selectedvalue then
            Response.redirect("www.bbc.co.uk")
        Else
            Response.redirect("~/guess-my-age.aspx")
        End If

        ddlAge.selectedvalue = 0


End Sub
```

**MICROSOFT SQL**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [selectProfilePicToGuess]

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT  TOP 1  accountID, contactName, city, mobilePhone, emailAddress, paypalEmailaddress, emailOptIn, profilePic
    FROM         tblAccounts
    ORDER BY NEWID()

END
```

Comment: Why are you yelling (caps)..? You've no need to yell.